# Disable button if value is null via Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, null

I have a reference in my `MainViewModel` which can be null at runtime. In that case I want a button (WPF) to disable itself, and if that refence isn't null anymore it should enable itself. I want to solve that task with a databinding, but I am not sure how to perform a null check a Databinding. My button:

```
<Button x:Name="SomeButton"   IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NullableProperty , Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: typically you would have a ICommand bound to that button, and this command would raise CanExecute=false when your property is null. This disables the button automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that you can set `TargetNullValue` of the Databinding to `false`, that does actually do everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using **DataTrigger**:

Example:

```
<Button Content="Click">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanContainNull}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>

    </Button>
```

and ViewModel Property:

```
public string CanContainNull
{
    get
    {
        return _canContainNull;
    }
    set
    {
        _canContainNull = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```